# How do I encode a hyphen in a Bash terminal's open command?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, svn, beyondcompare

I'm trying to write a small script that launches Beyond Compare when I do an svn diff. I got it working up until so far:

```
open -a /Applications/Beyond\ Compare.app "$6" "$7"
```

To get the full functionality, I need to add arguments with a hyphen (-, dash, minus sign)

```
open -a /Applications/Beyond\ Compare.app "$6" "$7" -title1="$3" -title2="$5" -readonly
```

But when I do that, the open command interprets the hyphens as flags for itself and exits with:

```
open: invalid option -- i
usage: ...
```

I tried "quoting" the entire command or - escaping the options. What should I do to get the extra functionality?

Comment: I am not familiar with OS X, but since you seem to be using bash: Can't you escape those with a backslah?  E.g. use `open -a /Applications/Beyond\ Compare.app "$6" "$7" \-title1="$3" \-title2="$5" \-readonly` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the open manpage :

```
 --args
     All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter to
     main(). These arguments are not opened or interpreted by the open tool.
```

So, your command would look like:

```
open -a /Applications/Beyond\ Compare.app "$6" "$7" --args -title1="$3" -title2="$5" -readonly
```